# Record video between points in waypoint mission

Tags: android, dji-sdk

I'm Using DJI mobile android SDK,
To create waypoint mission, with actions to shoot videos/photos in points.
I've tried to use `START_RECORD` action in a point, and then `STOP_RECORD` action in the next one.
But, that doesn't seem to work - no video file is created in SD card.

If the actions are set to the same point - the video file is created.

Is recording a video between points even possible using waypoint actions?
And if so, how can it be achieved?

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a guess here but are you using WaypointMissionFlightPathMode.CURVED?

You must use WaypointMissionFlightPathMode.NORMAL if you want actions to work properly.

I've used the actions are you describe and they function correctly (last time I checked).

Comment: Hi, I'm actually using the NORMAL property, as I wrote - the actions work, the only problem is that I can't start to record a video in one point, and stop record in the next point (recording the flight between points)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that you are not setting your camera mode to DJICameraModeRecordVideo before flying the waypoint mission. Try setting that before the waypoint.